# Why parenthesis are ignored in the expression (o.method)()

Tags: javascript

I want to understand why the parenthesis around `o.method` in the expression

```
(o.method)()
```

are ignored and so it's behaving equally to `o.method()`, with execution context of `method` referencing `o`. I was expecting it to behave similarly to `(o.method || true)()`, where execution context inside `method` references global object.

If I evaluate `(o.method)` on its own, it returns reference to a standalone function not bound to any context. Simply rewriting it like this

```
var a = (o.method); a();
```

will have global context as expected. And I've just shortened the code by replacing `a`, and it produced different result.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the parentheses question, but you can use `o.method.call()` to nullify the context

Comment: Also `true` is not a function

Comment: @naomik, yeah, I know, thanks, for some reason this question repeatedly gets understood in terms of execution context, and not parsing. Didn't understand your comment about the `true` not being a function

Comment: "o.method" just returns the function body. "Accessing a function without () will return the function definition"

Comment: @PAVANCHANDAKA queestion is, when `o.method` is called, `this` should have pointed to `window` and not to current object

Comment: @Maximus Just a curious question, Why do you expect it to have a global context? `setTimeout` or `setInterval` callbacks are pushed in event loop and are processed from there. IIFEs are executed as they are encountered. So should they not retain context?

Comment: @Rajesh, because just simply rewriting it like this `var a = (o.method); a();` will have global context. I've just shortened the code, and it produces different result. Are you sure it's parsed as IIFE? I was thinking that IIFE is relevant defining and calling a function, while it's defined somewhere before in my example

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622383/javascript-function-call-expression-for-object-member-functions , which is kind of a duplicate, but I know there is a much better duplicate that I've seen before

Comment: @Rajesh, I don't think there's such thing as IIFE in the context of how interpreter parses expressions :).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it has to do with [ES5 11.1.6](https://es5.github.io/#x11.1.6):

> 11.1.6 The Grouping Operator # Ⓣ
>
> The production `PrimaryExpression : ( Expression )` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Return the result of evaluating `Expression`. This may be of type Reference.
>
> **NOTE** This algorithm does not apply GetValue to the result of evaluating Expression. The principal motivation for this is so that operators such as `delete` and `typeof` may be applied to parenthesised expressions.

Let's see how function invocation is done in JS:

The key point is that `o.method` is a Reference (as defined by the spec):

> A Reference is a resolved name binding. A Reference consists of three components, the base value, the referenced name and the Boolean valued strict reference flag.

So, `o.method` is not a Function YET; it is basically `[[o, "method", false]]`. When invoked with an argument list, `o.method()`, the reference value is taken by GetValue, then the method invocation proceeds (as described in [11.2.3](https://es5.github.io/#x11.2.3)).

When you do `(o.method)()`, `(o.method)` is *still* a Reference - GetValue has still not been applied to it (per the quoted 11.1.6). So nothing changes.

When you do `(o.method || true)()`, `||` will apply GetValue to the left side (per [11.11](https://es5.github.io/#x11.11)) and produce a function value - not a Reference any more. Thus, it cannot be evaluated as a method invocation, since the information about the base and referenced name (that was present in Reference) is lost.

Comment: thanks, right to the point. You put `o` as the `base value` here `[[o, "method", false]]`, so is it correct to assume that when you define a function `foo` in global context and then reference it the `base value` is set to `window`, as in `[[window, "foo", false]]`?

Comment: @Maximus: Yes, that is my understanding as well. (Although I must admit I am a bit fuzzy on the "strictness reference flag", it is not relevant to this discussion.)

Comment: great, thanks. Also is my understanding correct that, on high level, `GetValue` follows the pointer to a memory address and retrieves the bits and interprets them as a function?

Comment: In more detail, `foo` is an [identifier](https://es5.github.io/#x11.1.2) that is resolved by [GetIdentifierReference](https://es5.github.io/#x10.2.2.1), walking up the environment chain until it hits the [global environment object](https://es5.github.io/#x10.2.3), which in the case of a browser environment is `window`. (Also, I figured out the strictness flag: it's the current strictness at the location where Reference is located, and, as I thought, is not relevant here.)

Comment: As for GetValue, [pretty much](https://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) - it resolves the reference and returns the value the reference points to. (Let's hope it's a function, or `o.method()` is in for a rude surprise.)

Comment: Got it, appreciate your help! Good luck)

Comment: Just rereading the answer, and I'm thinking what's in `a` in this statements `var a = (o.method); a();`? is it a reference or the function? it should be the reference, right? probably the _value_ is changed to global object, instead of `o`

Comment: No, it's a function. References don't exist in JavaScript - they only exist in the specification, and possibly in implementation, but there is no such type in the language itself. The reference will have GetValue applied to it when `var a = ...` is resolved, per `VariableDeclaration : Identifier Initialiser` rule in [12.2](https://es5.github.io/#x12.2). Actually, pretty much every evaluation in the language will apply GetValue, except for `delete`, `typeof`, grouping parentheses and left hand side in assignments and declarations (maybe I'm leaving a couple out, but not many).

Comment: thanks, sorry for additional questions, but I'm trying to get it right. You're saying that `a` is a function, so how come when we do `var b = a` we still have one function? I always thought that a variable sort of holds a reference to memory address where the actual value can be found (like pointers in `C`). Maybe I'm didn't understand what you were trying to say

Comment: Different meanings of "reference". "Reference" I was talking about is the one defined by ECMAScript (`[[base, name, strictness]]`), a specification type that does not exist in the language; "reference" you are talking about is, as you say, what we normally assume we are assigning when we do `b = a` instead copying objects. They are not the same thing. `{foo: 7}.foo` is a Reference (`[[{foo: 7}, "foo", false]]`) but not a "reference" (as `7` is a primitive type); `(Array.prototype || true)` is a "reference" (points to an object) but not a Reference (as it has been resolved by GetValue).

Comment: So yeah, `var b = a` will resolve `a` using GetValue, which means it stops being a Reference; but it will create a binding `b` that evaluates to the same exact value (not a clone of the value) as the binding `a`. If we change the value of `b`, the value of `a` changes accordingly. We say they "share a reference"; but this is an implementation detail. JS could also copy the value and then update every copy when one of them changes; this would be stupid and slow and stupid, but I think it would be compliant to the spec since it would evaluate the same way (without actually having "references").

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for the clarification! Appreciate)

Answer (score -3):

This is called **Method Invocation**.
When a function is stored as a property of an object, we call it a method. When a method is invoked, this is bound to that object. If an invocation expression contains a refinement (that is, a . dot expression or [subscript] expression), it is invoked as a method.

So in your case when you call o.method, this will refer to the object 'o'.

this will call to window object in case of function invocation.

Please refer : https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-good/9780596517748/ch04s03.html